# Most useful ActionScript packages / libraries

Tags: flash, actionscript, plugins, package

What are some useful plug-ins, packages or source-code for ActionScript?

Please include ActionScript version, name, link and description.

Answer (score 15):

Common libraries:

http://casalib.org/
http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/

Physics Engines:

http://box2dflash.sourceforge.net/ 
http://www.cove.org/ape/

Flash 3D engines:

http://away3d.com/ 
http://papervision3d.org/ 
http://alternativaplatform.com/en/ 
http://www.flashsandy.org/

Tweening:

http://greensock.com/gsap-as/ 
http://www.gskinner.com/libraries/gtween/

Graph/Chart + Particles:

http://flare.prefuse.org/demo/

Chart:

http://pullmonkey.com/projects/open_flash_chart

Particles:

http://flintparticles.org/

Game Engine:

https://code.google.com/p/pushbuttonengine/

Augmented Reality:

http://www.libspark.org/wiki/saqoosha/FLARToolKit/en

Answer (score 6):

Things I'm actually using from time to time:

[Degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/): Degrafa is a declarative graphics framework open source licensed under MIT. (AS3)

[FlexSpy](http://code.google.com/p/fxspy/): Visually inspect and tinker with display components. (Flex3)

[AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/): 100% client side PDF generation (AS3)

[PureMVC](http://puremvc.org/): MVC framework (many platforms...)

[Ravis Birdeye](http://code.google.com/p/birdeye/wiki/RaVis): Graph/Network visualization.

[FlexLib](http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/): Extended controls.

Answer (score 5):

AS2-AS3
[Greensock's TweenMax](http://blog.greensock.com/tweenmax/)
Simplifies creating animation in code.

Comment: Also, don't overlook TweenLite, which is incredibly lightweight and it will be more than enough for 99% of the tweenings you'll need.

Comment: I'll second this.  I use TweenMax/Lite on pretty much every project.

Answer (score 3):

A clear, lightweight and performant data structures / collections library:

[AS3Commons Collections](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-collections/)

Layout framework:

[AS3Commons UI - Layouts](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-ui/layouts/)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.robotlegs.org/

MVC Framework for flash/flex with dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

Shameles plug, but here it goes:
[BulkLoader](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/)
A library to manage a simultaneous loading operations.

Comment: Very handy lib.  I've used it successfully in a couple of projects that loaded up a large number of assets.  Pretty easy to tweak and extend too, which is nice.  Not hard at all to hook it up to a progress bar for the bulk load.

Comment: Thanks Alex, always nice to get some positive feedback!

Comment: I second this. Excellent lib, a must for any non-trivial RIA.

Answer (score 2):

[Mate](http://mate.asfusion.com/) tag-based, event-driven Flex framework. Obviously AS3 and Flex dependent.

[Axiis](http://www.axiis.org/) an open source data visualization framework. Built on [degrafa](http://www.degrafa.org/)

Answer (score 2):

## [Flixel](http://www.flixel.org/)

Flixel is an open source game-making library that is completely free for personal or commercial use. Written entirely in Actionscript 3, and designed to be used with free development tools, Flixel is easy to learn, extend and customize.

Answer (score 1):

A standard UI component library including with focus on customization, data intergration and performance. Including TreeView, ListView, SelectBox, ColorPicker, etc ...

[AS Data Provider Controls](http://sibirjak.com/blog/index.php/asdpc/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.unionplatform.com

A client/server framework for creating multiuser applications and multiplayer games.

Answer (score 0):

<Shameless self-plug>

[asMock](http://asmock.sourceforge.net/) : Dynamic mocking framework for AS3 with integration support for FlexUnit 1/4.0/4.1, ASUnit and fluint

</Shameless self-plug>

Answer (score 0):

it's powerful 2d library. you should try it ;) 
http://box2d.org/

Answer (score 0):

Did someone already mentioned [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling)?

I just discovered this a couple of days ago, so check by yourselves and if someone knows a little about it, I will be glad to know your opinion.

Best regards.
Nicolas.